# Searchview in the actionbar not work

Tags: android, searchview

I try to use the Search-view  in the action-bar, but after I click on the search button at the bottom of the keyboard nothing happen. I post my code below. Please neglate the packages names in the file. In my code I set the value of the searchview to the textView, it is not set. Log cat also not show anything else. Thank you in advance.

```
    Folder.java ------------------------------------



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.home, menu); 
    //----THIS ONE -----------
    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
    .getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
    .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    //----THIS ONE ---------------------------------------------------------------------------  
    // return true;
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    String filter_id = null,Tickets_title = null;
    int start_limit=0,page_no=1;

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (item.getItemId())
    { 
    case R.id.action_search:
    //Intent searchmenu = new Intent(Folders.this,SearchResultsActivity.class);

    //startActivity(searchmenu);
    return true;  

    default:
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    }   


    ------- SearchResultactivity --------------------

    package com.abc;
    import android.app.ActionBar;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.SearchManager;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class SearchResultsActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView txtQuery;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_results);

    // get the action bar
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    // Enabling Back navigation on Action Bar icon


    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    txtQuery = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtQuery);

    handleIntent(getIntent());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    setIntent(intent);
    handleIntent(intent);
    }

    /**
    * Handling intent data
    */
    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
    String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);



    /**
    * Use this query to display search results like 
    * 1. Getting the data from SQLite and showing in listview 
    * 2. Making webrequest and displaying the data 
    * For now we just display the query only
    */
    txtQuery.setText("Search Query: " + query);



    }

    }
    }

    ---------------- Activity_search_results.xml ------------------------
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.abc.Folders" >

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtQuery"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </RelativeLayout>


    ----------------------Searchable.xml -------------------------------

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint"
    android:label="@string/app_name" />

    -----------------------manifeast.xml ------------------------------
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.abc"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.5" >

    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="24"/>

    <!-- Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages.-->
    <permission
    android:name="com.abc.pqr.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>



    <!-- Initially app name and logo as the blank starts -->

    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/blank3"
    android:alpha="120"
    android:label=""
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme"> 
    <!-- Initially app name and logo as the blank ends -->

    <activity
    android:name="com.abc.pqr"
    android:label="" ><!-- @string/app_name --><!-- app name blank if present it shows 2-3 sec when start the activity , we have to change it -->
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <!-- THIS ONE  -->
    <meta-data
    android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
    android:value=".SearchResultsActivity" />
    <!--  THIS ONE ENDS -->

    </activity>


    <!-- Search results activity -->
    <activity android:name=".SearchResultsActivity"
    android:parentActivityName="com.abc.Folders" >
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
    android:name="android.app.searchable"
    android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>
    </application>

    </manifest>
```

Hello Answer is,

Just add the following lines in the manifeast files under particular activity.In which u want to show your searchview.

Comment: Please suggest if any solution...!

Comment: post your menu.xml which contains search view Item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Rajesh this is the menu.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:panelFullBackground="#ffff"  >
<!-- THIS ONE FOR SEARCH ITEMS -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
android:title="@string/action_search"
android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"/>

<!-- THIS ONE FOR GLOBAL SEARCH ITEMS -->

</menu>
```

Hi all ,the problem is solved ....I just added the 
 
 
 
This code in the particular activity where i write code for the Search Functionaliy.

Comment: Hi all ,the problem is solved ....I just added the  <!-- THIS ONE  -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                android:value=".SearchResultsActivity" />
            <!--  THIS ONE ENDS -->   This code in the particular activity where i write code for the Search Functionaliy.

Comment: Hi @SandeepT, please make this answer in your post by [editing it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41312454/edit) and write your comment above, in an answer. Thanks